# How do I run an Eclipse launcher file in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, launch

I have a Eclipse `.launch` file that a developer has created to set up the classpath, vm and program arguments from a XML file that Eclipse uses to launch the program.

I want to be able to run this file in **IntelliJ IDEA** but is there an automatic way without manually creating the settings?

Comment: When you see the end of http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/usingIDEAforEclipse.html#Final_project_structure ... not sure if there is an automatic import

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IDEA [doesn't support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-2476) importing Eclipse .launch files.

A workaround is to use the third-party [Eclipser plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7153-eclipser).

> Eclipser can convert the following Eclipse launch configurations into
>   IntelliJ IDEA run configurations:
>
> - Local Java application Eclipse launcher
> - Program launch Eclipse launcher (converted into external tool in Tools menu)
> - Maven launch configuration
> - Remote Java application Eclipse launcher
> - Ant launch configuration

Comment: That's a shame as developers on my team cannot jump to IntelliJ as they do not want to manual convert these .launch files.

Comment: yep, Ive added a vote for the issue to be addressed I recommend you all do the same

Comment: @HaveAGuess wat do you mean with adding a vote. Anyway, as the Eclipser plugin solves the problem, I think it makes sense then to simply use the plugin.

Comment: @miss_R sounds like things have changed since the five years we wrote this then! I meant vote on the bug linked in CrazyCoder's answer :)

Comment: @HaveAGuess where is this answer?

Comment: @algolicious, the accepted answer is outdated and now wrong.  You should accept the newer, correct answer.

Answer (score 26):

Try the Eclipser plugin

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pluginId=7153

> Eclipser will automatically convert Eclipse launch configurations into
>   IntelliJ IDEA configurations

However it currently (as of November 2014) supports only very limited number of launch types:

> - local Java application (...)
> - program launch (...)
> - Maven launcher (...)

See https://github.com/kukido/eclipser/wiki for details.

Comment: [Eclipser](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pluginId=7153) developer is here. Thanks to @jean-michel-garcia for the answer above. I would like to add that as of today, Eclipser supports the following formats: - Local Java application Eclipse launcher - Program launch Eclipse launcher - Maven launch configuration - Remote Java application Eclipse launcher - Ant launch configuration And I'm working on JUnit launch configuration conversion. Give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

steps to launch eclipse launcher in intellij

1. download the plugin
2. install it in intellij
3. restart intellij
4. right click .launch
5. click "convert with eclipser"
6. check run/debug configurations, an new application process should be added
7. check working directory is correct or not, if not fix it
8. run that process, eclipse launcher can be executed

Comment: "an new application process should be added" means new maven runner

Answer (score 0):

For thouse, who wants to launch *.product* file in idea - see [this manual](https://sites.google.com/site/javafornewbie/frameworks-tools/eclipse/eclipse-rcp-application-development-with-idea)