# How to run Eclipse .launch file in Intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I was using Eclipse for a while to develop a Java/web project, we have some scripts with the ending .launch. The file to be launched starts with the following two lines:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
> <launchConfiguration
> type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
```

Now I have started to work with IntelliJ?

Comment: I have installed eclipser plugin but still don't know how to use it

Comment: Here is the recipe to launch it using eclipser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389446/how-do-i-run-a-eclipse-launcher-file-in-intellij-idea/16965426

Answer (score 10, accepted):

steps to launch eclipse launcher in intellij

1. [download](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7153-eclipser) the plugin
2. install it in intellij
3. restart intellij
4. right click .launch
5. click "convert with eclipser"
6. check run/debug configurations, an new application process should be added
7. check working directory is correct or not, if not fix it
8. run that process, eclipse launcher can be executed

Here is the recipe to launch it using eclipser

[How do I run an Eclipse launcher file in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389446/how-do-i-run-a-eclipse-launcher-file-in-intellij-idea/16965426)

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: do we have solution for new IntelliJ 2023

Answer (score 0):

For a new version of Intellij, you would need to download the older version.

- compatibility of versions:
  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7153-eclipser/versions
- idea old versions:
  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html

convert and then use converted properties in the new version of Intellij:)